# Run exe file from php eclipse?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using PHP eclipse and i configured Eclipse for Python. I can run python scripts from eclipse.But my problem is how to run `.exe` in python file in Eclipse? I want to execute  `pdftotext.exe` from Python file in Eclipse. I can run this python file from command prompt.

```
from subprocess import call
import csv

call(["pdftotext.exe","-f", "2", "-l", "2","sample.pdf"])

lines = open('samplet.txt').readlines()
open('newfile.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[40:-1])

txt_file = r"newfile.txt"
csv_file = r"mycsv.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = ' ')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'wb'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the *full file system path* to both `pdftotext.exe` and `sample.pdf` in your `call` method arguments:

```
pdf_to_text = r"C:/Users/YourUserName/Desktop/pdftotext.exe"
call([pdf_to_text,"-f", "2", "-l", "2", r"C:/sample.pdf"])
```

In addition, make sure you add the full file system path for `newfile.txt` as well, so something like:

```
txt_file = r"C:/Users/YourUserName/Desktop/newfile.txt"
```